# Comunicar n mandatos distintos con pipes en C

Tags: c, pipe

tengo un pequeño programa que ejecuta dos comandos conectados por un pipe en este caso `ls | wc` y me gustaría generalizarlos para n comandos, por ejemplo, `ls | cat | wc` o `ls -l | wc -l`

Mi programa es el siguiente:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){

int fd[2];
pid_t pid;

    if(pipe(fd)<0){
           perror(“Error al crear la tubería”);
           return1;
    }

    pid = fork();
    
    switch(pid){
         case -1:
             perror(“fork”);
             return 1;
```

En el hijo ejecuto el primer comando ls

```
case 0: 
             close(fd[0]);
             close(STDOUT_FILENO);
             dup(fd[1]);
             close(fd[1]);
             execlp(“ls”, “ls”,NULL);
             perror(“exec”);
             return 1;
             break;
```

Aquí en el padre ejecuto el segundo comando wc

```
default:
            close(fd[1]);
            close(STDIN_FILENO);
            dup(fd[0]);
            close(fd[0]);
            execlp(“wc”, “wc”,NULL);
            perror(“Error en el exec”);
      return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

¿Qué cambios debería hacer y cuáles? ¿Pueden ayudarme? Gracias!